# C - Combine las three bits of a byte with a byte

Tags: c, byte, bit

Lets say I have this byte in binary: f=  01010111, then I'll do this: f<<3 so Im expecting: 10111000, at this point Im going to have another byte, lets say the other one is 10111001 and I want to attach them so the result is 1011110111001. Basiclly, what I want is that the last three bits from the first byte to get swap for the second byte.

I have no idea how can I do this, can you help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use 16 bit numbers? Also you should check out some bitwise tutorials, there is a lot of material on the subject.

Comment: I have seen a lot but all the tutorials I find are pretty basic, what I recieve is a text (the text has numbers, characters etc..) then I change it to binary and do this, so at the end I think is going to be a really long chain of 010101..... Im encrypting the text.


Im a "noobie" on byte use so I dont know if I can do this hahaha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
uint8_t f = 0x57; // 0b01010111
f <<= 3;          // now 10111000
uint8_t g = 0xB9; // 0b10111001
uint16_t out = (f << 5) | g;
printf("0x%04X\n", out);

> 0x17B9          // 0b1011110111001
```

I don't understand the intermediate `<< 3` but I'm assuming it's part of your application.